# 'Require is not defined' when adding electron-renderer to webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron

I am developing an electron app. All good and nice until I wanted to use IPC from the renderer to call some native features. I understand that adding the following line to my Webpack config would allow me to import electron on the renderer side.

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    target: 'electron-renderer',
}
```

I get the following error when adding this line

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

And the offending line is

```
module.exports = require("querystring");
```

Which sort of makes sense, since the browser does not understand "requires".

Note that without the `electron-renderer` target the application works well, except I cannot do things like

```
import {ipcRenderer} from 'electron';
```

Any thoughts what I could be doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Just recently ran into this. One thing to look out for is to ensure nodeIntegration is set to true when creating your renderer windows.

```
mainWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that `nodeIntegration: true` is generally **INSECURE**.
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security

Comment: @AndreiCioara would love to know if you solved this mate, `nodeIntegration: true` was already true for me and I'm getting this error.

Comment: So FYI, every single article on this topic says the same thing - set nodeIntegration to true. 

What do you do when nodeIntegration is, and has been set to true, yet "require is not defined" still occurs?

Comment: I too am still having this issue and nodeIntegration is set to true also.

Comment: I was struggling with this issue myself, still getting "require is not defined" with `nodeIntegration: true`. Setting `contextIsolation: false` as well got it to start working for me.

Answer (score 14):

Also faced this issue, new answer:

```js
mainWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU the recommended way is to use `contextBridge` module (in the `preload.js` script). It allows you to keep the context isolation enabled but safely expose your APIs to the context the website is running in.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation

Following this way, I also found that it was no longer necessary to specify `target` property in the Webpack config.